# Need to separate out Letters from numbers in a string, via vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, excel, visual-studio

I would like my code to find anywhere in the string that there is a number next to a letter and insert a space between the two.

I have several addresses that have no spaces and I need to insert spaces by separating out the numbers from the letters. For example:

123MainSt.Box123

Should be 123 Main St. Box 123

or

123Parkway134

should be: 123 Parkway 134

Here is where I started with my code but it was combing both numbers in the beginning....

```
Dim Digits() As String = Regex.Split(Address, "[^0-9]+")
        'MsgBox(Digits.Count)
        If Digits.Length > 2 Then

            ' For Each item As String In Digits

            Dim Letters As String = Regex.Replace(Address, "(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)", "")

            rCell.Value = Digits(0) & Letters & Digits(1)

        End If

        If Digits.Length < 3 Then
            If Address.Contains("th") Then
            Else

                Dim Part1 As String = Regex.Replace(Address, "[^0-9]+", "")
                Dim Part2 As String = Regex.Replace(Address, "(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)", "")
                'MsgBox(Part1 & " " & Part2)
                rCell.Value = Part1 & " " & Part2
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: Actually, from your example it looks like starting with the second character in your string you just want to put a space in front of every capital letter and every digit that is not followed by another digit.  Something you can do with a for loop.

Comment: Rob, im leaning more towards putting a space between wherever a letter and number are together within the string....

Comment: you're the boss - see answer below

Comment: A regex approach to insert spaces in between a number and a digit is a mere `Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)", " ")`. There is a way with capturing groups and a match evaluator, but the code would look horrible. However, your code above implies you need something more specific (like ignoring ordinal numeral suffixes,etc.). Please clarify.

Comment: Also, do not forget to accept the answers that worked for you and upvote those that were helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like my code to find anywhere in the string that there is a number next to a letter and insert a space between the two.

The regex you may use is

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)", " ")
```

The first alternative - `(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})` - matches the location between a digit and a letter, and the second alternative - `(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)` - matches a location between a letter and a digit.

Note that `(?<=\p{L})` is a positive lookbehind that requires a letter before the current position and `(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead that requires a digit after the current position. These are lookarounds that do not consume text, thus, you replace empty spaces with (= insert)  a space.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Is it possible to insert spaces at special characters like (\_) and (.) that are often used in filenames?
Here is your very promising approach, as you know it leaves out the special characters like (.) and (\_). Is that possible?
https://rubular.com/r/Q92iW17MALZPD7

Comment: @snahl What output do you expect to obtain for `_NKC2422_3_4_5_6.tif`?

Comment: Thanks for asking. 2 options would good:
Opt1: `$1='_NKC' $2='2422' $3='_3_4_5_' $4='6' $5='.' $6='tif'`
Opt2: `$1='_NKC' $2='2422' $3='_3' $4='_4' $5='_5' $6='_6' $7='.' $8='tif'`
What matters is that the first and last number(s) in this case $2 and $6 of a filename string are captured (if possible).
Some to filename is longer: eg. `_NKC2521_2_3_4_5_6_7.jpg` or shorter `_NKC2631_2_3.jpg`. Those are generated by some imaging software that I cannot adjust within the application. 
There are more special cases for filenames I'm struggling with. Maybe I better post it as whole new question.

Comment: @snahl You said you wanted to insert a space but in the above comment you show a match structure. It is not still clear to me what you actually want, but [here is a `[._]+|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)` demo](https://regex101.com/r/XeVvYK/1) where each one or more `.` or `_` are also replaced with a space.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! I think I can keep going with that example you have provided above.
On the other hand, could the same be applied for a match structure? I could then use the returned matches ($).

Comment: Bummer, but apparently Microsofts VBscript does not support 'lookbehinds'. Is there a possibility to get a somewhat equal result with MS VBscript? (I aware that old VBscripts ought to be converted to Powershell, but that would take me ages to finish).

Comment: @snahl This question is about VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of being in the VB.NET section. However how could I apply your last example in Powershell? That would help my decision on how to proceed. I promise, this is the last question in this wrong section.

Comment: @snahl In PS, it is straight-forward, `(Get-Content -path $filepath) -replace '[._]+|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)', ' '`

Comment: Get-Content in fact reads the megabytes of the whole image. The following works fine for me recursively: `(Get-ChildItem $filepath -File -Recurse) | 
 Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ("[-]+|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)", " ")}`. Thanks, Goal accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick function:

```
 Private Function AddSpaces(ByVal input As String) As String

    If input.Length < 2 Then Return input

    Dim ReturnValue As String = String.Empty
    Dim CurrentChar, NextChar As String

    For x As Integer = 1 To input.Length

        CurrentChar = Mid(input, x, 1)
        NextChar = Mid(input, x + 1, 1)

        ReturnValue &= CurrentChar

        If (IsNumeric(CurrentChar) AndAlso (Not IsNumeric(NextChar))) OrElse
           ((Not IsNumeric(CurrentChar)) AndAlso IsNumeric(NextChar)) Then
            ReturnValue &= " "
        End If

    Next

    Return ReturnValue

End Function
```